# login password web service Java

Tags: web-services, apache, tomcat, logging, apache-axis

i'm developping a mobile application in Android and blackberry, I want that Users can connect from their Smartphones to Webservice witch will verify their login and password in an Oracle Database, I should maintain connection between Client and server within Sessions.

my webservice should be under apache Tomcat using Axis2.

how can I implement this Session via Soap Messages ???

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

its best if you could get this without having to maintain sessions. if maintaining session is a must, you'll have to pass authentication details with each soap request along with a token or a session status object where at each end you'll be manually updating with status.